# How to insert the data of tree by the NLR way

Tags: c++, tree, binary-search-tree, nodes

> I have a code C++ about inserting the tree's data and printing them out by the NLR method. But after inserting the data, i can't print the tree by using command 2 in menu.
>
> I know the problem is somewhere in "insertTree" but idk how to fix it

```
struct node {
    int data;
    node* left;
    node* right;
};
void insertTree(node* t, int x) {
    //if the node to add is root
    if (t->data == NULL) {
        node* p = new node();
        p->data = x;
        p->left = NULL;
        p->right = NULL;
        t = p;
    }
    else {
        //if the added element is less than t
        if (t->data > x) {
            insertTree(t->left, x);//add the element to the left of t
        }
        else if(t->data < x) {
            insertTree(t->right, x);//add the element to the left of t
        }
    }
}
void duyet_NLR(node* t) {
    if (t->data != NULL) {
        cout << t->data << " ";
        duyet_NLR(t->left);
        duyet_NLR(t->right);
        system("pause");
    }
}
```

Comment: Recommendation: Back up the code and remove all of the user input. Hard code a tree that exposes the error you want help with and does as little else as possible. Use [mre] as inspiration. If making and playing with the smaller, targeted example doesn't lead to you answer, replace the code in the question with the new example.

Comment: Sidequestion: What do you think `if (t->data == NULL)` does? `data` isn't a pointer so you shouldn't compare it with `NULL`. If you want to check if it's zero, then use `0`. I suspect that all your `t->data` comparisons with `NULL` should really be comparing `t` with `NULL` - and btw, don't use `NULL`. Use `nullptr`.

Comment: I expect this program crashes the first time it calls `insertTree` or `duyet_NLR`, since the first thing these functions do is dereference a null pointer.

Comment: Also, you only change the local variable `t` in the insert function so the root node pointer will be unchanged at the callsite. It should probably be: `void insertTree(node*& t, int x)`

Comment: chimsedibui, did you get the points I made in the answer or do you want me to clarify anything further?

Comment: Thank you so much!! I understood your idea

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two (or three) big problems in the program:

- All the checks where you check `if (t->data == NULL)` or `if (t->data != NULL)` are wrong. You need to check if **`t`** is a null pointer. `t->data` is an `int` and shouldn't be compared with `NULL`. Also, don't use `NULL` in C++. Use `nullptr`. In this case it would have helped you because the program wouldn't compile if you had used `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.
- The `node*` `t` in `insertTree` is local to the function. Any changes you do to it will not be visible to the caller of the function (that is, in `menu`). This can be changed by taking a reference to the pointer:

  ```cpp
  void insertTree(node*& t, int x)  // note a reference to the pointer
  ```
- The same problem as in the point above exists in `menu`. When `menu` returns to `main`, the pointer in `main` is still a null pointer - so you can't delete all the nodes afterwards. Make the same change there:

  ```cpp
  void menu(node*& t)
  ```

Using recursion to insert nodes is probably not a problem, but you could avoid it by looping inside `insertTree` to find the insertion point. Example:

```cpp
void insertTree(node*& t, int x) {
    node** next = &t;

    while(*next) { // loop until a leaf node is found
        if((*next)->data > x) next = &(*next)->left;
        else if((*next)->data < x) next = &(*next)->right;
        // this value already exists in the tree
        else return;
    }

    // *next is here a null pointer so that's where we'll insert the new node
    *next = new node{x, nullptr, nullptr};
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/a7154r9v1)

You also need to add a function to free all the allocated memory.

Comment: Thank for your explaining!!!
Can u explain the last sentence for me "You also need to add a function to free all the allocated memory". I don't quite understand this

Comment: @chimsedibui You're welcome! For every `new` that you do, there should be exactly one `delete` (on the pointer returned by `new`). The same goes for `new[]`/`delete[]`. If you don't free the memory, your program is said to "have a memory leak". That is, it allocates memory but doesn't release the memory back when done with it. For programs designed to work for a long time, this becomes a program since they will eventually run out of memory. If you looked at my demo, you can see that I've enabled the "LeakSanitizer" which reports the memory leak at the end of the program execution.

Comment: @chimsedibui I addeda [`freeTree`](https://godbolt.org/z/n9Pnec7nG) function to the demo to show how it could be done.

Comment: Yeahh i see. That's big problem i have to solve. Thank u